# Axios post request with nested object

Tags: python, django, reactjs, postgresql, axios

I need help with axios post with multiple student objects in one single class. Class form has various fields with an option to add dynamically multiple students. Add only student names for the objects but be able to edit the student details to give full details.Backend is Django.

Post request without objects works. Frontend with Axios adding dynamic fields works. But I am not sure how to post objects with the form fields.

```
                                 <Form.Item >
                                    <Button type="secondary" onClick={this.add}>
                                        <Icon type="plus" /> Add student Details
                                        </Button>
                                </Form.Item>
                                {formItems}
                ` 
            for (let i = 0; i < values.students.length; i += 1) 
             {
             students.push(     
             studentName: values.students[i],
            });
            }`
```

{

```
    "students": [
        {

            "stud_fname": "First Name",
            "inter_lname": "Last Name",
            "class_section": "class",

        },
        {

            "stud_fname": "First dsfdsfName",
            "inter_lname": "Last sdfName",
            "class_section": "cladsfdfss",

        }
    ],
    "ClassName": "eqwe",
    "TeacherName": "eqw",
    "SchoolNAme": "eqw",

}
```

Comment: Please be a bit more specific when asking a question: *What have you tried so far with a code example?* / *What do you expect?* / *What error do you get?* **For Help take a look at "[How to ask](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"**

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [ask] to understand how to formulate a good question. And also how to make a [mcve]. Right now, you're not telling us your specific issue, nor showing any code that causes the issue.

Comment: I added details, I couldnt' add complete code here. But as of now , post request works without objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with and adjust accordingly -

```
  `axios.post(
            `http://localhost.com:8000//`,
            values.students.map(d => ({
              stud_fname: d
            })
)
)`
```

Comment: Students is one table and course is another table. While adding student name, my requirement is to create new student record and have reference to course id to student table. So, should I add axios.post(
            `http://localhost.com:8000//`, to students url or course url ??. And do I need to make 2 post requests to add all fields of course to course and students names to students record? I am totally confused. Please help

Comment: how have you linked courses with student in your django app?

Comment: Every course has multiple students. Course = models.ForeignKey(
        Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='', null=True)

Comment: make 2 request, first to add courses. so suppose you have 10 courses added. now make another request to add student. In student model set course = model.foreignkey(course) if each student have one course or modify to use many course.  When adding student send the id of course along with student data. practice more to get things clear.  so at the time of adding student you only have to do one post request, or before adding get the id of course.

Comment: Thank you for the inputs. Actually the requirement is different. Forget about student and course. There are 2 forms, and 2 models. In 1st form, I would like to add names of 2nd form dynamically with a plus option.  Each name corresponds to a separate record of 2nd form. This is the reason this post's heading is Axios post with a nested objects. I understand it how to do it separately. So, I have to post from the form one: 1st form fields + objects of 2nd model from 1st form

Answer (score 0):

you can use filter option to filter only student name like below

```
.get("http://localhost:8000/api/snippets/")
  .then(res => {
    this.setState({ restaurants: res.data.filter(res.name) });
  })
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```